# Color Matplotlib Histogram Subplots by a Categorical Variable

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to create histogram subplots whose values I want to color by a second, categorical variable.
A small subset of the data is below

```
data = {'ift': [0.031967, 0.067416, 0.091275, 0.046852, 0.100406],
        'ine': [0.078384, 0.09554, 0.234695, 0.182821, 0.190237],
        'ift_out': [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        'ine_out': [1, 1, 0, 0, 1]}

xyz = pd.DataFrame(data)
xyz
```

My initial stab at it is also below. A bit stumped on the inclusion of the categorical columns as colors

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharey=True, tight_layout=True)


axs[0].hist(xyz['ift']) # color = xyz['ift_out']
axs[1].hist(xyz['ine']) # color = xyz['ine_out']
plt.show()
```

Sample output is attached below

[image: histogram]

Comment: This is one of the main use cases for Seaborn.  E.g. `sns.histplot(data=xyz, x='ift', hue='ift_out', palette=['tomato','skyblue'], multiple='stack', ax=axs[0])`

Answer (score 0):

Following @JohanC's answer, I made the some changes to my original code as shown below, and that worked they way I wanted

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.color_palette("tab10")
sns.set(style="darkgrid")

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, tight_layout=True)

g = sns.histplot(data=xyz, x='ift', 
                 hue='ift_out', palette=['skyblue','tomato'], multiple='stack', ax=axs[0])
g = sns.histplot(data=xyz, x='ine',
                 hue='ine_out', palette=['skyblue','tomato'], multiple='stack', ax=axs[1])
```